# How to debug this VBA/Excel code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have source VBA and the problem is how I stop Ontime in if else.

```
Sub ok2()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "test", Schedule:=True
End Sub
Sub ok3()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "test", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub test()
    If i < 50 Then
        UserForm2.Label1.Width = i * 2
        i = i + 1
        ok2
    Else
       ok3
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what problem you're trying to fix is as there is little detail in the question, but by looking at your script, have you tried adding `Call` before `ok2` and `ok3` in `Sub test()`?

Comment: hi pro, my button click call sub ok2, and then...

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that explains the problem you're having or the question you're asking. *VBA exel* is in the tags, so it means nothing in the title. *Help me please* conveys nothing, either; if you didn't need help you wouldn't be posting here. Your title should be something that will be useful to future readers when they see it in a search result.

Answer (score 1):

to cancel OnTime, you need to also provide the exact time of the schedule when it is set.

consider the following for your reference

```
Option Explicit

Private SetTimer As Date

Sub ok2()
    Application.OnTime SetTimer, "test", Schedule:=True
End Sub
Sub ok3()
    Application.OnTime SetTimer, "test", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub testTimer()
    If MsgBox("test", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        SetTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
        ok2
    Else
       ok3
    End If
End Sub


sub test
    msgbox Now
end sub
```

---

You **cannot** stop ontime using

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "test", Schedule:=False
```

You need to provide the exact time it was scheduled to run in the EarliestTime param.

E.g. When `Now` is 17:00:00 and you run `ok2`,

This means `test` will run at 17:00:01 because `Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")` will be 17:00:01 at that time.

So, to stop it, you must run the following code

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:00:01"), "test", Schedule:=False
```

Observe that there is no `Now` in the statement, i.e. the **exact** time of the schedule must be provided.

Comment: hi bro, my problem is how to stop ontime

Comment: yes i understand. please see my updated answer. HTH

Comment: you are welcome. pls mark this as answer if it resolve your problem. TQ